# androidのwebviewでピンチインピンチアウトのコントローラーを非表示

Tags: android, webview

webviewの設定で、

下記のように設定しないとピンチインアウトが出来ないのですが、
Controllerを非表示にできないのでしょうか？

```
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

下記を設定したら非表示に出来ました。
APIが11以上で対応しているようです。

```
settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```